# Why does unmountComponentAtNode give me "another copy of React" warning

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, charts

I want to display a chart.js/chart in a bootstrap popover. I do this by defining two components one for the Popover and one for the Chart. In my Popover component I handle the componentDidMount() and override the template for the popover, giving the popover body an id so I can mount my chart into the popover body:

```
componentDidMount() {
    $("#button").popover({
    title: "My Chart",
    template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header"></h3><div class="popover-body" id="popover-body"></div></div>',
    html: true,
    trigger: "focus"
   }).popover("show");
   ReactDOM.render(<MyChart/>, document.getElementById('popover-body'));
  }
```

And then I try to unmount my chart component when the Popover component is unmounted:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('popover-body'))
    $("#button").popover("hide");
  }
```

But this gives me the warning:

> Warning: unmountComponentAtNode(): The node you're attempting to
>   unmount was rendered by another copy of React

Why am I getting this error? Isn't the Popover component the parent of the Chart component? And I am handling everything in my state change as one should?

Complete example at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrxjthod/)

Comment: are you using the same instance of ReactDOM for both?

Comment: @Doc-Han do you need to use the same instance of ReactDOM to remove a component? That may explain why my compoents do not unmount: I have "ReactDOM.render" inside one project, and "ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode" in another project.